# Allowing "Unknown Publisher" application to launch from IE

Tags: windows, internet-explorer

We have a 3rd-party system that uses an XBAP app, which is launched from Internet Explorer. More often than not, when it starts up, it displays an "Unknown Publisher" warning:

[image]

To even run the application and get this far, it has to be part of IE's "Trusted Sites". However, even with `Launching applications and unsafe files` set to `Enabled`, users are still prompted:

[image]

Does anyone know what setting needs to be configured to stop this prompt appearing, and more importantly what registry key(s) or Group Policy setting do we need to change so we can push this out across all users?

Answer (score 0):

You need to whitelist the specific `Class ID` of the Applet in Group Policy. You definitely **don not** want to whitelist all "Unknown Publisher" Applets.

## Locate Class ID

You can find the `Class ID` by opening the Manage Add-ons dialog in Internet Explorer.  `Class ID` is a hidden column by default, it can be enabled by right-clicking a column header and selecting the Class ID column to display:

[image: Screencap of Manage Add-ons window]

## Setup Group Policy

Armed with the `Class ID` GUID, the following location in Group Policy manages the handling of IE Add-ons as per their `Class ID`:

**`Computer Configuration\Policies\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Internet Explorer\Security Features\Add-on Management`**

Here, you may create an array of `Class IDs`, and specify a `Value` setting the following:

- Value = 0. The add-on is disabled and your employees can’t change it.
- Value = 1. The add-on is enabled and your employees can’t change it.
- Value = 2. The add-on is enabled and your employees can change it.

Using the `Values`, you can specifically whitelist OR blacklist add-ons, and also give users flexibility to self-manage.  If two add-ons conflict for some reason, you may need to specify a **`value`** of **`2`** so users can self-manage.

Reference: [TechNet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn454941.aspx)

Comment: Thanks: unfortunately, however, I can't see any sign of the application in any of the "Add-on" category: even when selecting "All add-ons", the only one that's listed is `HtmlDlgSafeHelper Class`. This is from IE whilst the downloaded Applet is running, but "Currently loaded add-ons" is empty!

Comment: I will trawl through registry. This has to be somewhere.

Comment: Do you see anything unique to your XBAP application here: **HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\ProtocolExecute**?

Comment: I think `HtmlDlgSafeHelper` is only up while the sandboxed XBAP app is running.  The whole virtualized/sandboxed nature of XBAP apps seems to be a problem here.

Comment: I'm afraid there's no `ProtocolExecute` key under HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer on my system :(